# How to append lists (coming out of a for loop) to another existing list in scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a List of Maps as below:

```
myListOfMaps= List[Map(studentId -> 1234, status -> active),
                   Map(studentId ->5678, status -> inactive)...]
```

I'm processing each Map and it's elements in this List using "for/yield" and creating a list like below:

```
for (x <- myMap) yield {
  ...
  ...
  list(studentId,1234)
}
```

Now, there's another existing List (`List(a,b,cd)`) and I want to append each list coming out of the "for/yield" loop to this. So, my expected output is:
`List(a,b,c,d,studentId,1234,status,inactive...)`. How to do this?
I can add `newList= List(a,b,cd) ++ list(studentId,1234)`, but it's NOT appending the list values coming out of the for loop.

Comment: It seems your final list has elements of many types, which will end in a **List[Any]** _(which is a code smell)_. Are you sure you want that? Also mutability is another code smell. It would be good if you explain the problem you are trying to solve, maybe there are more typesafe ways.

Comment: My final list would be the sum of all the lists coming out of the "for" loop + the original List. I have tried the solution provided by @pme below and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Scala* you should try to avoid *Mutability* when ever possible.

Here is a solution using a `for-comprehension`:

```
List("a", "b", "cd") ++
  (for{
    myMap <- myListOfMaps  // -> List(Map(studentId -> 1234, status -> active), Map(studentId -> 5678, ...     
    (k, v) <- myMap        // -> List((studentId, 1234), (status, active), ..
  } yield List(k, v))      // -> List(List(studentId, 1234), List(status, active), ..
  .flatten
```

This returns `List(a, b, cd, studentId, 1234, status, active, studentId, 5678...`

Which is a new List, that you can work with.

`flatten` is needed as you have a `List[List[_]]` and you want a `List[_]`.

By the way "for/yield" loop is called `for-comprehension` in Scala.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: @pme its cool. How did ++work? Are you assigning the whole thing to another variable? ` val finalList = (for{....} yield List(k, v)).flatten`

Comment: @Salim you can do whatever you like. `++` will create a new List of 2 Lists. So `val listNew = list1 ++ list2` for example. So as a rule, try always to avoid `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Using scala.collection.immutable.List and var. List is immutable so when you append one list to another using ++ it give another list and it wouldn't happens to the 1st list.

```
    var a = List("a","b")
    val b = List("a1","b1")

    a = a ++ b //a is var so same variable can be reassigned.

    println(a)
```

Using scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer. ListBuffer being mutable can be changed using ++=

```
    val a1 = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer("a","b")
    val b1 = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer("a1","b1")

    a1 ++= b1

    println(a1.toList)
```

Comment: That is correct. But, my main issue was getting lists appended to main List ( the lists were generating from "for" loop). I have tried the solution provided by @pme above and it works